# Delta Detection in Oracle table with 2 billion records using composite key

Tags: oracle

Initial Load on Day 1

| id | key | fkid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 100 |
| 1 | 1 | 200 |
| 2 | 0 | 300 |

Load on Day 2

| id | key | fkid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 100 |
| 1 | 1 | 200 |
| 2 | 0 | 300 |
| 3 | 1 | 400 |
| 4 | 0 | 500 |

Need to find delta records
Load on Day 2

| id | key | address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 400 |
| 4 | 0 | 500 |

**Problem Statement**
Need to find delta records in minimum time with following facts
1: I have to process around 2 billion records initially from a table as mentioned below
2: Also need to find delta with minimal time so that I can process it quickly

**Questions** :
1: Will it be a time consuming process to identify delta especially during production downtime ?
2: How long should it take to identify delta with 3 numeric columns in a table out of which
id & key  forms a composite key.

**Solution tried** :
1: Use full join and extract delta with case nvl condition but looks to be costly.

````
    nvl(node1.id, node2.id) id,
    nvl(node1.key, node2.key) key,
    nvl(node1.fkid, node2.fkid) fkid
FROM
    TABLE_DAY_1       node1
    FULL JOIN TABLE_DAY_2   node2 ON node2.id = node1.id
WHERE
    node2.id IS NULL
    OR node1.id IS NULL;```
````

Comment: We need DDL of table, more info on the time line (do you have gaps in the dates?), and better examples of data and expected result (you show only "added" rows: what about missing ones?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two separate statements to handle this, one to detect new & changed rows, a separate one to detect deleted rows.

While it is cumberson to write, the fastest comparison is field-by-field, so:

```
SELECT /*+ parallel(8) full(node1) full(node2) USE_HASH(node1 node) */ *
  FROM table_day_1 node1,
       table_day_2 node2
 WHERE node1.id = node2.id(+)
   AND (node2.id IS NULL -- new rows
        OR node1.col1 <> node2.col2 -- changed val on non-nullable col
        OR NVL(node1.col3,' ') <> NVL(node2.col3,' ') -- changed val on nullable string
        OR NVL(node1.col4,-1) <> NVL(node2.col4,-1) -- changed val on nullable numeric, etc..
       )
```

Then for deleted rows:

```
SELECT /*+ parallel(8) full(node1) full(node2) USE_HASH(node1 node) */ node2.id
  FROM table_day_1 node1,
       table_day_2 node2
 WHERE node1.id(+) = node2.id
   AND node1.id IS NULL -- deleted rows
```

You will want to make sure Oracle does a full table scan. If you have lots of CPUs and parallel query is enabled on your database, make sure the query uses parallel query (hence the hint). And you want a hash join between them. Work with your DBA to ensure you have enough temporary space to pull this off, and enough PGA to at least handle this with a single pass workarea rather than multipass.

Comment: Since this table is a versioned table so no delete/update case will be there but in general to identify delta by processing 2 billion rows how long it should take just an idea ? Since there would be only 3 columns in src and target table

Comment: I'm afraid that's not a question anybody outside your organization can answer. Time depends on the degree of parallelism you have, your CPU architecture, your I/O throughput from storage, how much memory overflows to temp from the hash join, etc.. But to give you an idea, I regularly see 2-billion row inputs to hash joins with 16 parallel slaves take in the neighborhood of 10 minutes. In slower systems that could be an hour or more.